# Capitalize the last letter in a string (with letters and numbers) using jQuery

Tags: jquery, capitalize

I'm using the following jQuery to capitalize the 1st letter of an input script.

```
$('li.capitalize input').keyup(function(event) {
    var textBox = event.target;
    var start = textBox.selectionStart;
    var end = textBox.selectionEnd;
    textBox.value = textBox.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + textBox.value.slice(1);
    textBox.setSelectionRange(start, end);
});
```

In addition, I now need to capitalize a letter at a specific position (not the first letter) in a string comprising letters and numbers.

For example: **Da1234Z**
I need to capitalize both **D** and **Z**.

How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe i'm paranoid but this sounds a lot like a homework question.

Comment: So, what if the string is "23fz980q7"? Are you wanting to capitalize the F and the Q?

Comment: @MageeWorld, we allow homework. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all.
I got to capitalize the 7th letter like this:

```
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('li.capitalize input').keyup(function(event) {
var textBox = event.target;
var start = textBox.selectionStart;
var end = textBox.selectionEnd;
textBox.value = textBox.value.slice(0,7) + textBox.value.charAt(7).toUpperCase() + textBox.value.slice(8);
textBox.setSelectionRange(start, end);
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function to capitalize the n-th character of a string:

```
function capitalizeNth(text, n) {
    return (n > 0 ? text.slice(0, n) : '') + text.charAt(n).toUpperCase() + (n < text.length - 1 ? text.slice(n+1) : '')
}
```

If you know that n can't be negative you can even shorten it to:

```
function capitalizeNth(text, n) {
    return text.slice(0,n) + text.charAt(n).toUpperCase() + text.slice(n+1)
}
```